# Term for original function used to derive anti-derivative and derivative

Tags: calculus, soft-question

In analyzing a function, $f(x)$, it is often useful or necessary to analyze its antiderivate $F(x)$ and/or its derivative $f'(x)$. Does $f(x)$ have a special name that I can use to refer back to it in the same way that I can refer to $f'(x)$ as 'the derivative' and $F(x)$ as 'the antiderivative'? Just calling $f(x)$ 'the function' is bound to cause confusion. I thought about using 'the output function' or 'the original function' but these are non technical terms.

Comment: Let $f$ be the *function* in question. To the function $f'$ we call it the *derivative* of $f$ (not only "the derivative"). Similarly, any function $g$ with the property $g'=f$ we call it an *antiderivative* of $f$ (notice that I wrote "an antiderivative" instead of "the derivative").

Comment: And, answering your question, there is no "technical" term to refer to the "original" function, since we do not know exactly what it is for a function to be the original or the initial one.